# Linear algebra - For symmetric matrix X $\in S^n$, prove the $a^T X a$ = $\det X \det(X_{n-1})$ , where $a_i$ = $(-1)^i M_{in} $

Tags: linear-algebra, oc.optimization-and-control, determinants, semidefinite-programming

Suppose we have a symmetric matrix X$\in S^n$, and $X_k$ denotes the submatrix consists of first $k$ rows and columns of X. If $\det X < 0$, but $\det X_1, ..., \det X_{n-1} > 0$. Let $a_i=(-1)^i M_{in}$, where $M_{in}$ is the determinant of the $(i,n)$-th minor of X, that is, the matrix by removing the  $i$-th row and the$n$-th column of X. Prove $a^T X a = \det X \times \det X_{n-1}$.\

I know that $\det X$ = $\sum_{i=1}^n |X_{in}|a_i$, and $\det X_{n-1} (-1)^n = a_n$, but have no idea how to show $a^T X a = \det X \times \det X_{n-1}$ from these conditions. By the way, I also noticed that $X_{n-1}$ is positive definite and tried to use Schur complement, but also couldn't figure it out. Can someone help me with this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Recognise $a^T $ as the last row of the adjugate matrix of $X$, and recall that the product of this adjugate matrix with $X $ is $\det X$ times the identity matrix.

Comment: Aha, thanks for the hint :) I will try to work it out!